# Deserializing nested dynamic data structure

Tags: c#, json, web-services

Lets say I have a web service that looks like this:

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    Response SomeCall(IList<Parameters> parameters);
}
```

and Parameters is a class with many properties, one of which is a different "class" called Data

```
public class Parameters
{

    ...

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data data{ get; set; }

    ...
```

Data is supposed to be a completely dynamic class. Maybe it only contains a value, maybe it contains a subclass.

The json of a request could look like this:

```
"Parameters":[
     {
        " id ":" A0132001 - testData ",
        " data ":{
           " A0132001 - testData ":{
              " foo ":" 05 ",
              " bar ":" 1 ",
              " boo ":" 050 ",
              " far ":" Y "
           }
        }
     },
     {
        " id ":" A0555001 - testData ",
        " data ":{
           " value " : " test "
           }
        }
     },
     ...
  ]
```

Is there a way to parse a request in such a way that the Data property does not need a prefedined class structure with all possible values, without touching the rest of the Parameters class? I tried setting data to dynamic, but that just yields null on deserialization.

Comment: What you are describing is quite possibly an _anti-pattern_.  Neither the caller nor the recipient knows what consitutes a valid request, what is valid data and more importantly _what to do with it_.  You may as well define the method as `Response SomeCall(IList<object> parameters);`.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing, just exploring my options. The reason behind this is that the caller knows their own structure, and will from time to time add new types of Parameters with new structures. We are only forwarding this specific part of the data, so Im looking for a way to minimize maintenance on our side by making a specific field generic. I hope that makes sense

Comment: _"the caller knows their own structure"_ - why is the caller calling the shots?  Considering you are making an API you should dictate what is allowed (unless of course this data represents some blob your app cares not for).   Your service method is a contract, if they send something different they are breaking the contract.  If however at some point in the future additional data is required you should make a V2 of the contract interface.  Depending on your audience and app type, published contracts should never change.  https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/